# Does stunnel support multiple forwardings over the same connection?

Tags: port-forwarding, remote, putty, local, stunnel

A lot of the tutorials on [stunnel](http://stunnel.org) show only single forwardings. It stunnel limited to only fowarding and listening to one port on both ends, or can it handle both local and remote forwarding in the way putty, my favorite does?

Eg in putty or ssh you can do something like ssh -L xxxx:localhost:yyyyy -L aaa:localhost:bbbbb -R yyyyy:somehost:zzzz user@host.com. Does stunnel do the same over a single connection, or is it limited by SSL from doing so, who requires another separate connection?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "over the same connection"?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I have added more detail to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single instance of `stunnel` can support multiple proxy configurations.  For example, see [this configuration](http://portal.sbgrid.org/docs/usr_doc/stunnel-4.15/stunnel.conf-sample) I found on Google, which is configured to proxy `pop`, `imap`, and `smtp`.

This is not exactly the same as what you can do with the proxy support (`-L` and `-R`) in ssh.  When using ssh, you're talking to an ssh server which is able to negotiate with your client to create all the forwardings you have requested.  Stunnel simply sets up whatever is defined in the stunnel configuration file.